# Run python test modules independtly

Tags: python, testing

I have two different modules (test_a.py, test_b.py) with tests written using unittest.Tescase under one unique folder (tests_folder). If I run the tests of each module with:

```
python -m unittest tests_folder.test_a.py
python -m unittest tests_folder.test_b.py
```

They all pass, but if I run the command:

```
python -m unittest discover tests_folder
```

Tests fail. I know this is happenning because of mocking, since I am mocking some classes in one module which are aleady imported in the other module which makes mocking not working. So I need to run the modules completely independet. Is there any way for doing this?
Thanks!!

EDIT:
I have prepared a small project for testing. With next folders:

```
project/
├── __init__.py
├── src
│   ├── class_A.py
│   ├── class_B.py
│   ├── class_C.py
│   └── __init__.py
└── tests
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── test_1_class_B.py
    └── test_2_class_C.py
```

Where `class_B` imports `class_A` and `class_C` imports `class_A`and `class_B`. All classes are empty clases and tests only run the `__init__` method. I have added a print message at the beginning of each module to check when each one of them is entered.

When I run `python -m unittest discover -v project.tests` I have the next prints:

```
Tests for B
Module B
Module A
Tests for C
```

So this means that if in `test_2_class_C` I mock `class_B.B` it will not take effect since it was already imported in the tests for B and it is not imported again. This would cause all tests pass if they are run independently but they will fail with the discover command.

Comment: It doesn't matter if a module is already imported, take care that you patched a target method before **calling** it and mocking will succeed.

Comment: In fact, it does matter in some cases. If I want to mock a class that appears as a static attribute in another, I am force to do the mocking before the import statement or it will have no effect. This causes the module tests pass independtly, but when together if the import has already been executed in other module it will not be able to patch it.

Comment: It's called **unit** tests and the main difference with integration tests is that your test shouldn't depend on anything else. Prepare your environment, mock that class including its class level attributes, and then call your method. Please provide your minimal code and I'll explain you how.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky part with mocking (calling `patch()`) is to use correct target.

It is possible to mock `B` in `test_2_class_c.py` with the code below.

Classes.

```
# src/class_a.py
print("Module A")


class A:
    def __init__(self):
        print(self.a())

    def a(self):
        return "A"

# src/class_b.py
from src.class_a import A

print("Module B")


class B:
    def __init__(self):
        A()
        print(self.b())

    def b(self):
        return "B"

# src/class_c.py
from src.class_a import A
from src.class_b import B


class C:
    def __init__(self):
        A()
        B()
        print("C")
```

Tests.

```
# tests/test_1_class_b.py
import unittest

from src.class_b import B

print("Tests for B")


class ClassBTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_b(self):
        print()
        B()

# tests/test_2_class_c.py
import unittest
from unittest.mock import patch

from src.class_c import C

print("Tests for C")


class ClassCTestCase(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_c(self):
        print()
        C()

    @patch("src.class_c.A.a")
    @patch("src.class_c.B.b")
    def test_c_mock_a_b(self, mock_b, mock_a):
        print()
        mock_a.return_value = "X"
        mock_b.return_value = "Y"
        C()
```

Output.

```
$ python -m unittest discover -v tests
Module A
Module B
Tests for B
Tests for C
test_b (test_1_class_b.ClassBTestCase) ... 
A
B
ok
test_c (test_2_class_c.ClassCTestCase) ... 
A
A
B
C
ok
test_c_mock_a_b (test_2_class_c.ClassCTestCase) ... 
X
X
Y
C
ok

----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 3 tests in 0.001s

OK
```

These aren't real tests (as there are no asserts), but the printed output shows mocking is possible.